# Nodejs pug form button not redirect and submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

When I fill in the information in the form in the add-product.pug file, the information should appear as a card on the home page and should be returned to the "/" directory as a redirect, but it does not happen.
I cut some parts when i click submit button nothing happens

add-product.pug form

```
    form(action='/admin/add-product', method='POST')
    .form-group.row.my-3
        label.col-sm-2.col-form-label(for='name') Product Name
        .col-sm-10
            input.form-control#name(type='text', name='name')
    .form-group.row
        .col-sm-10.offset-sm-2.my-3
            input(type="submit" value="Submit").btn.btn-primary
```

admin.js

```
const products = [
    {name : 'Samsung S8', price: 3000, image: 'image1.jpeg', description:'iyi telefon'},
    {name : 'Samsung S7', price: 3000, image: 'image2.jpeg' ,description:'idare eder'},
    {name : 'Samsung S6', price: 3000, image: 'image3.jpeg' ,description:'çok iyi'},
    {name : 'Samsung S5', price: 3000, image: 'image4.jpeg' ,description:'güzel telefon'},
]


router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('add-product',{title:'Add a New Product'});
});



router.post('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
    products.push({name:req.body.name,price:req.body.price,image:req.body.image,description:req.body.description});
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
});

exports.routes=router;
exports.products=products;
```

user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const admin= require('./admin');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Homepage', products: admin.products });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')



app.set('view engine','pug');
app.set('views','./views');




const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const admin = require('./routes/admin');



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


app.use('/admin', admin.routes);
app.use(userRoutes);



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors

Comment: no when i just click submit button nothing happens

Comment: If your code is indented the same way as it is in your question, your `<form>` element will be empty in the compiled HTML. There's nothing indented underneath it. Have you inspected the HTML in the browser to verify it's as you expect?